# Datatable column filter with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I am using DataTables version 1.10.12 and bootstrap 3 datepicker v4.17.42. I set the clearBtn as true.

HTML code:

```
    <td>
        <div class="datepicker input-group date" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
         <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" readonly placeholder="From">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-sm default" type="button">
           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </button>
         </span>
        </div>
   </td>
```

Datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    clearBtn: true
});
```

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiT4j.png)

Whenever I try to clear the input of the datepicker, the table doesn't draw. I tried placing an id on the datepicker clear button itself, but nothing happens.

Failed attempt:

```
$('#clear-date').click(function() {
        table.draw();
});
```

Is there a solution to this? Thank you in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: Hook into one of the Datepicker events (`update` or `change`) and refresh the table in there. If it doesn't refresh then it is likely using old filter parameters so make sure you are settings them correctly

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I used the cleardate event.

Comment: I notice you haven't accepted any answers to your questions. Accepting answers will increase your Rep and reward those that have helped you. Just something to think about

Comment: Yes, I understand and apologise for that. I am new here and I am still figuring out how this website works.